# How do I mount an .iso with another (live CD) .iso?

Tags: lvm, live-cd, loopback, qemu

I want to:

1. Place the .iso of a live CD in a directory.
2. Use qemu (kvm or kqemu) to run the .iso
3. Put a 2nd live CD .iso in the same directory.
4. Have the 1st live CD mount the 2nd .iso.

Say, I have 2 .iso files in the same directory,
how can I emulate one and mount the 2nd
from within the 1st?

--
Wishing you Happiness, Joy, and Laugher,
Drew Brown

Answer (score 9):

I assume that both the ISO images are located **outside** the virtual file-system. From the KVM man pages, the option that you are looking for is `-drive` instead of `-cdrom`.

Instead of -cdrom you should be able to define even multiple cd-roms and mount them from within the live-cd. They should appear as `/dev/hda` to `/dev/hdd` in the VM.

```
qemu -drive file=filepath,index=0,media=cdrom
qemu -drive file=filepath,index=1,media=cdrom
qemu -drive file=filepath,index=2,media=cdrom
qemu -drive file=filepath,index=3,media=cdrom
```

Where **filepath** is the path to the image you want to mount.

Answer (score 2):

To run from a live CD, you just need to specify it when starting quemu, as in

```
qemu -cdrom myiso.iso
```

To mount a second live CD, that in principle works as under regular Linux:

```
mount -o loop disk1.iso /mnt/disk
```

(must be done as root, mountpount /mnt/disk is arbitrary, but must exist).

You just need to arrange to put your 2nd iso into a directory where the QEMU VM can see it (or copy it over the net etc.).